# Water leaking at hose-faucet quick connector

Tags: water, faucet, hose

I have a faucet positioned near the ground at the entrance of my home. I use it for watering the lawn by connecting a ~40m hose to it via an adapter (blue) and a quick connector.

If I don't connect a hose, everything is fine, water is running without leaking. But after connecting a hose, the water starts leaking from all possible places in the quick connector (even under little pressure).

I noticed that water runs back out of the hose when I just pour it without connecting - is it normal? Is it what causes the leak?

Could the problem be in very low positioning of the faucet relative to the ground?

Note that I tried 2 different connectors, 2 different adapters and 3 different hoses.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Difficult to be sure. Could you clarify "water runs back out of the hose when I just pour it without connecting"? One possible problem is that many hose accessories have pressure limits below those of many household water systems, and in that case a pressure reducer before the quick-connect might help (there are inexpensive versions made specifically for hoses.)

Comment: By "water runs out" I mean that if I diconnect the hose from the connector completely and just slowly pour water straight into it, the water does not go down completely, part of it flows back from the hose.
I don't think it's pressure, as happens even under small pressure (when tap is slightly turned)